# JavaScript date to MySQL datetime conversion

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, datetime

I have a js date variable

```
var date = "2017-01-23T10:17:50.285Z";
```

I have stored this in MySQL table and the column have type `DATETIME`

after storing in the database the value in the table looks like this:

[image]

Now when I am trying to get the record from the database using this column name I am doing like this:

```
var mysqlFormate = new Date(date).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

which is giving the output as `2017-01-23 10:17:50`

**The problem**

You can see the value stored in the database is different than the converted value (`2017-01-23 15:47:50`  and `2017-01-23 10:17:50` are different).

So I am not able to get the data from the database using this column.

What can be the possible mistake I am doing here? Thanks.

Comment: Probably a timezone problem. You have exactly 5h30 minutes difference between client and server. The server should normally stay in UTC. Try showing the time client-side by using `Date.UTC()`

Answer (score 0):

Check How you could set Time Zone information on SQL Server(or follow a convention).

in

```
new Date(date).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
```

Replace the toISOString with formatLocalDate() with the below definition

```
function formatLocalDate() {
var now = new Date(),
    tzo = -now.getTimezoneOffset(),
    dif = tzo >= 0 ? '+' : '-',
    pad = function(num) {
        var norm = Math.abs(Math.floor(num));
        return (norm < 10 ? '0' : '') + norm;
    };
return now.getFullYear() 
    + '-' + pad(now.getMonth()+1)
    + '-' + pad(now.getDate())
    + 'T' + pad(now.getHours())
    + ':' + pad(now.getMinutes()) 
    + ':' + pad(now.getSeconds()) 
    + dif + pad(tzo / 60) 
    + ':' + pad(tzo % 60);
}
```

there's a clear **5h30m** so I presume you're converting(or forgetting) the GMT to IST Offset.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the local time in JS there is `Date.UTC()` function it tells the browser that the date you're about to give it is expressed in UTC, that way, the browser will apply the required conversion and show it as local time.

```
function getLocalTime(mysqlDate) {
    var dateTime = mysqlDate.split(' ');
    var date = dateTime[0].split('-');
    var time = dateTime[1].split(':');
    var utc = Date.UTC(date[0], date[1], date[2], time[0], time[1], time[2]);
    return new Date(utc);   
}
```